# Spring mvc: jsp failed to access to css file

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm going to implement a guestbook web app using spring mvc framework. I have a problem with accessing to css file from jsp. From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500861/how-to-reference-a-css-file-from-a-view-jsp-in-spring-mvc), I have just learned that /web-app/WEB-INF act as a private repository and my server don't want expose it. In order to access to css file from jsp, I created style folder, into which I put `templatemo2.css`. But I still have the problem. Eclipse says,

> 6? 29, 2014 4:18:38 ?? org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/Guestbook/sytle/templatemo2.css] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'Guestbook'

my jsp file refers to **(hello.jsp)**

```
<link href="sytle/templatemo2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

directory structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: Check your spelling on `sytle`. You also should configure a resource handler so Spring won't try to map the request to a handler method.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-default-servlet-handler